# Looking for better Sql Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to update `@tblData` table's `LastDateTime` column with `MAX ChildDateTime` of table `@tblChildData` and `IsLast` = 1.

```
Declare @tblData Table(DId Int, TypeId Int, LastDateTime DateTime)
Insert Into @tblData Values(1, 1, Null), (2, 2, Null), (3, 2, Null)

Declare @tblChildData Table(CId Int, DId Int, ChildDateTime DateTime, IsLast Bit)
Insert Into @tblChildData Values (10, 1, '2016-09-20 07:47:03.000', Null)
    , (11, 2, '2016-09-20 08:47:03.000', Null)
    , (12, 2, '2016-09-20 09:32:03.000', 1)
    , (13, 2, '2016-09-20 10:47:03.000', Null)
    , (14, 2, '2016-09-20 11:32:03.000', 1)
    , (15, 1, '2016-09-20 06:47:03.000', Null)
```

I am able to update by below query, but looking for better query. Thanks!!!

```
UPDATE UQ
SET UQ.LastDateTime = (
    SELECT MAX(D.ChildDateTime)
    FROM @tblData C
    JOIN @tblChildData D ON C.DId = D.DId
        AND C.TypeId = 2
        AND D.IsLast = 1
)
FROM @tblData UQ
JOIN @tblChildData PD ON UQ.DId = PD.DId
    AND UQ.TypeId = 2
    AND PD.IsLast = 1

SELECT * FROM @tblData
```

Comment: thanks for better editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try update like this:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.lastDateTime = (SELECT
  MAX(childDatetime)
FROM @tblChildData
WHERE did = t.did
AND IsLast = 1)
FROM @tblData t
```

Not sure why you joined with childdata again below. Check the output with your expected output. Obviously it will perform better as it does not join the other table second time. Below is the execution plan comparison between your query

My update script

[image]

Your Update script

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
UPDATE UQ SET UQ.LastDateTime = (
SELECT MAX(D.ChildDateTime)
FROM @tblChildData D where D.DId=UQ.DId
    AND UQ.TypeId = 2
    AND D.IsLast = 1) FROM @tblData UQ where UQ.TypeId = 2
```